# How to solve this double series

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}(i+j)$$

How do I solve this in terms of n? My ultimate goal is to find a function, g(n) that this series is Big Omega of, aka it grows as fast as g(n). I need to figure out what the order of growth of the algorithm that is represented by this series is.

I have tried to find identities, example problems, or something like this question with no luck.

I also attempted to expand the inner series, and then reduce it in terms of i, and then apply other identities to reduce it further, with no luck.

P.S. This is school related, but I will not be copying and pasting the answer into my any assignment, I just want to understand the solution.

Comment: Please don't use pictures, use MathJax. Here is a       
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Oh sorry I did not see that in the rules.

Comment: Sorry, here is a link for why not to use pictures. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Given all you tried, please show your work, up to when you got stuck.  But don't claim effort when you don't provide the workings.  We all get stuck, but sometimes due to a simple error, meaning one has the correct idea.  But we cannot help without knowing more from you.  This is not a "do my work for me" service.

Comment: If you just need the order of magnitude, note that $(i+j)\in \Theta(j)$ (for any fixed $i$); so $\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}(i+j)\in \Theta(i^2)$; and finally $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}(i+j) \in \Theta(n^3)$.  That being said, you should be able to evaluate the whole expression exactly, starting with the inner sum.

Comment: Which identities did you try? Or which examples? or can you show your work when expanding the series?  So two sentences you wrote are meaningless, in terms of helping us help you.  [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|127.9065).  Read the linked post, and return to improve your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\left(i+j\right) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}i + \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}j\right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(i^2 + \frac{(0+i-1)i}{2}\right) \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{3}{2}i^2-\frac{i}{2}\right)\\
&= \frac{3}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^2-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i \\
&= \frac{3}{2}\frac{(n-1)(n-1 + 1)(2(n-1)+1)}{6}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(1+(n-1))(n-1)}{2} \\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left((n-1)n(2n-1)-(n-1)n\right) = \frac{n(n-1)^2}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Hi @Eugene how did you get $i^2$ and $\frac{(0+i-1)i}{2}$ from the first to the second step.

Comment: $\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}i = \underbrace{i + \ldots + i}_{i\text{ times}} = i^2$ -- this is a sum, where common term ($i$) doesn't depend on the summation index ($j$), so it is basically adding $i$ $i$ times.

$\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}j$ is a sum of the first $i$ terms of the [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), with the first term equal to 0, and the difference $d = 1$.

Comment: Perfect, I believe the rest makes sense. Thank you kind stranger.